# Creating and deploying pre-trained tensorflow model with pre-processing and post-processing in AWS SageMaker

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy the pre-trained MaskRCNN model of https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN in SageMaker for prediction.

The problem is that the model uses numpy and scikit-learn as preprocessing before feeding inputs to the Keras layers, so just deploying the model as in [this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-script-mode/tree/master/tf-2-word-embeddings) would not work.

Things I have tried:

- Isolating the Keras part of the model and using this, so that the model to be deployed in the endpoint uses the data pre-processed. The problem in this case is that an http error `431 Request Header Fields Too Large` is prompted, since the pre-processed data (formed by the resized images plus anchors) is way larger than the original data.
- Making an `entry_point.py` script with the `input_handler()` function. This script looks like the following:

```
def install(package: str):
    """ pip install a package """
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-q", "-m", "pip", "install", package])

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR'))
    return parser.parse_known_args()

def input_handler(data, context):
    """ Expects @data to be json. Pre-process the data to be ready to be fed to the Keras layers. 
    https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/custom-preprocessing-in-tensorflow-with-sagemaker-endpoints/ """

    data_dec = np.array(json.loads(data['inputs']))

    [molded_images, image_metas, anchors] = preprocess_images(data_dec)

    inputs = { #input_image, input_image_meta and input_anchors are the names of the Input layers of the model
        "inputs": {
            "input_image": molded_images.tolist(),
            "input_image_meta": image_metas.tolist(),
            "input_anchors": anchors.tolist()
        }
    }

    return json.dumps(inputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    args, _ = parse_args()

    install('scikit-image')
    install('scipy')
```

And then creating the model and the endpoint in a SageMaker Notebook Instance:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = url_to_saved_model_s3,
                        role = sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                        framework_version = '2.3.1',
                        entry_point = 'entry_point.py' 
                        )
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.t2.medium') # create endpoint
```

But does not look like the `input_handler()` is ever called.

Any help on how to deploy a model for inference that needs to pre-process non-tensors?

Answer (score 0):

so you can work with numpy and sklearn in your script. You merely need to create a requirements.txt with these packages in your code directory with your entry point script. As for the input_handler and output_handler functionality, you want to build it in the following format as shown in the [SageMaker Tensorflow Serving Container](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container).

```
import json

def input_handler(data, context):
    """ Pre-process request input before it is sent to TensorFlow Serving REST API
    Args:
        data (obj): the request data, in format of dict or string
        context (Context): an object containing request and configuration details
    Returns:
        (dict): a JSON-serializable dict that contains request body and headers
    """
    if context.request_content_type == 'application/json':
        # pass through json (assumes it's correctly formed)
        d = data.read().decode('utf-8')
        return d if len(d) else ''

    if context.request_content_type == 'text/csv':
        # very simple csv handler
        return json.dumps({
            'instances': [float(x) for x in data.read().decode('utf-8').split(',')]
        })

    raise ValueError('{{"error": "unsupported content type {}"}}'.format(
        context.request_content_type or "unknown"))


def output_handler(data, context):
    """Post-process TensorFlow Serving output before it is returned to the client.
    Args:
        data (obj): the TensorFlow serving response
        context (Context): an object containing request and configuration details
    Returns:
        (bytes, string): data to return to client, response content type
    """
    if data.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(data.content.decode('utf-8'))

    response_content_type = context.accept_header
    prediction = data.content
    return prediction, response_content_type
```

Make sure to log each line of your functions, this will emit to CloudWatch and we will get an idea of the error that you are dealing with and you could see where your script is breaking.